# PHP parse error bracket expected

Tags: php

When I run the following PHP code:

```
<?php

$start = "https://en.wikipedia.org";

function follow_links($url) {

    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML(file_get_contents($url));

    $linklist = $doc->getElementsByTagName("a");

    foreach ($linklist = $link) {
        echo $link->getAttribute("href")."\n";
    }
}

follow_links($start);
```

**Error:**

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 12

What am I doing wrong, because I swear that I have closed all brackets correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change this

```
foreach ($linklist = $link) {
```

to this..

```
foreach ($linklist as $link) {
```

Comment: thanks, to used to assigning variables in other languages, never really used php before.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `foreach` loop to this.  [foreach reference](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

```
foreach ($linklist as $link) {
        echo $link->getAttribute("href")."\n";
    }
```